# downloading .zip file with maximum file size limit

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, download

I am developing project in asp.net, c# 2010. In that i am trying to download mp3 files in .zip format. It works fine in local PC even if size is between 80 to 150 MB. It also works on live server while .zip file size is between `10 to 20 MB` but now i have uploaded files that are between `80 to 150 MB` and It not works and not gives any error only loading page. Page is loading may be because i have set maximum timeout in `web.config` file.

**Downloading code**

```
if (File.Exists(virtualPath))
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(virtualPath);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(AlbumName) + "\"");
    Response.AppendHeader("content-length", file.Length.ToString());
    Response.WriteFile(virtualPath);
    //Response.End();
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000000" executionTimeout="999999"/>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
   <security>
       <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" />
       </requestFiltering>
   </security>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Don't know what's the reason. Please help me to solve this error. If you have alternate solutions it would be great.

**Edit**

```
if (File.Exists(virtualPath))
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(virtualPath);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(AlbumName) + "\"");
    Response.AppendHeader("content-length", file.Length.ToString());
    Response.Buffer = false; 
    Response.TransmitFile(virtualPath);
    //Response.WriteFile(virtualPath);
    //Response.End();
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there an IIS related error? Look in the event viewer.

Comment: May be its IIS related error but i am not sure. How can i use event viewer ?

Comment: From the start menu: event viewer

Comment: Depending on your version of windows it might be start -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(virtualpath))`, it will turn buffering off and you don't have to write to the output stream.

Comment: Hi ps2goat: I am getting `The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80072746.` exception after using `Response.Buffer = false; Response.TransmitFile(virtualPath);` and removed `Response.WriteFile(virtualPath);`. can you help me for this issue ?

Comment: add logging-- how long does it take between starting the download and the error occurring?  Did the session expire?  E.g., did you quit interacting with the web site for a long time, longer than your session timeout?

Comment: Hi ps2goat: Thanks for your quick response. It's taking less then 30 - 40 seconds. And i think it's not cause of session expire or timeout issue. May be something strange happening during downloading. Though it alert box with download option.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line before WriteFile:

```
Response.Buffer = false;
```

Comment: i am getting error like: **The connection was reset**
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Comment: This statement needs to come first.

Comment: Hi richardtallent: see my edit code. i am using this for now but i am getting this error. `The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80072746.` In which place i have to put `Response.Buffer = false;` this statement ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a IIS setting called:

> **maxAllowedContentLength**
>
> Optional uint attribute.
>
> Specifies the maximum length of content in a request, in bytes.
>
> The default value is 30000000.

Guess you have to change your IIS settings to allow Files over 30MB.

In webconfig the `maxRequestLength` is measured in kB!

> Open the file
>   C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config and find the
>   line:
>
> Set the overrideModeDefault property to Allow. So now the line should
>   look like:
>
> `<section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />`

Comment: I have already set `maxRequestLength` in web.config. You can see my question. i have added that.

Comment: check if overrideModeDefault="Allow" is set

Comment: Thanks Nikolaj Zander, In that its `overrideModeDefault="Allow"`. Any way problem solved by using `Response.TransmitFile(virtualPath)` file instead `Response.WriteFile(virtualPath)`. Thanks for your valuable reply.