# OutOfMemoryException whilst downloading file IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7.5, download

we have a page that does:

```
        Response.Clear()

        If fileext = "docx" Then
            strContentType = "msword"
        Else
            strContentType = fileext
        End If

        Response.ContentType = "application/" & strContentType
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & DocID & "." & fileext)
        Response.WriteFile(docpath)
        Response.End()
        Response.Flush()
```

which is generally working, but recently we have been receiving an OutOfMemoryException error when the download files are large than 15MB. Our test system is identical, as far as I have checked, but we have not been able to replicate the issue there.

At a bit of a loss what is affecting this.

John

Comment: There's a similar question here that might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480556/downloading-zip-file-with-maximum-file-size-limit

Comment: thanks for replying, it turns out that was similar but not quite the same. We recycled the app pool and web instance in IIS out of hours last night, which seems to have resolved it, but I don't know for how long